# How do I install torbrowser 4.0.3 in Ubuntu 14.10 using tar command?

Tags: tar, install-from-source, tor-browser

When I enter the command: `tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-4.0.3_LANG.tar.xz` It gives me this error:

```
tar (child): tor-browser-linux32-4.0.3_LANG.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Did I enter something wrong? I did download it from the tor website in the *tar.xz* format. If I must tell it to look at the download folder, how do I do this?

Comment: makes sure the entered filename is correct and you have the same file in your current directory.

Comment: I copied the command straight from the website and pasted it into terminal. That wrong? the file lies in my downloaded folder. Must the command be changed?

Comment: what is the name of downloaded file? Is that the same name as you typed in command? if not change it to file name in your download dir.

Comment: Also make sure that you have changed directories using `cd` to your your downloaded folder where the file is located, as KasiyA said in the first comment. The tar command looks for tor-browser-linux32-4.0.3_LANG.tar.xz in your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

As [documented in official source](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux) after [downloading the architecture-appropriate file](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads), save it somewhere, then run one of the following two commands to extract the package archive:

1. Switch to directory that you download the `tor-browser-linux[32-64]-4.0.3_LANG.tar.xz` file there and run:

   For the 32-bit version

   ```
   tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-4.0.3_LANG.tar.xz
   ```

   or (for the 64-bit version):

   ```
   tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux64-4.0.3_LANG.tar.xz
   ```

   (where **LANG** is the language listed in the filename (see also below list)).
2. Once that's done, switch to the Tor browser directory by running:

   ```
   cd tor-browser_LANG
   ```

   (where **LANG** is the language listed in the filename).
3. Finally to run Tor Browser, execute the `start-tor-browser` script:

   ```
   ./start-tor-browser
   ```

   This will launch Tor Launcher and once that connects to Tor, it will launch Firefox. 
   Do not unpack or run TBB(Tor-Browser-Bundle) as root.

---

All available value for **LANG** are in this syntax `Language (LANG)`:

```
English (en-US)
العربية (ar)
Deutsch (de)
Español (es-ES)
فارسی (fa)
Français (fr)
Italiano (it)
Korean (ko)
Nederlands (nl)
Polish (pl)
Português (pt-PT)
Русский (ru)
Türkçe (tr)
Vietnamese (vi)
简体字 (zh-CN)
```

---

For an example if you downloaded 32-bit version with English language, your commands would be:

```
cd /path/to/where/tor-is-downloded
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-4.0.3_en-US.tar.xz
cd tor-browser_en-US
./start-tor-browser
```

or if you downloaded 64-bit version:

```
cd /path/to/where/tor-is-downloded
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux64-4.0.3_en-US.tar.xz
cd tor-browser_en-US
./start-tor-browser
```

For an easier usage, do this:

```
sudo ln -sf /path/to/where/tor-is-downloded/tor-browser_LANG/start-tor-browser /usr/bin/tor
```

To start Tor-browser, just open a Terminal, type `tor` and hit enter.

[image]

---

#### Optional, to remove Tor-Browser, do:

```
[sudo] rm -r /path/to/where/tor-is-downloded/tor-browser_en-US/ /usr/bin/tor ~/.tor-browser-en
```